# How can I pass a typealias as a function parameter in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics, ios8, type-alias

Is it possible to pass a `typealias` as a function parameter in Swift?
I want to do something like:
`func doSomethingWithType(type: typealias)`

Comment: Could you clarify? Do you want to pass the type or an object of that type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A type alias is just a synonym for an existing type - it doesn't create a new type, it just create a new name.

That said, if you want to pass a type to a function, you can make it generic, and define it as follows:

```
func doSomething<T>(type: T.Type) {
    println(type)
}
```

You can invoke it by passing a type - for instance:

```
doSomething(String.self)
```

which will print

```
"Swift.String"
```

If you define a typealias for `String`, the output won't change though:

```
typealias MyString = String
doSomething(MyString.self)
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for that. This along the lines of what I was trying to do. My issue being that the library I'm using in the function call that now receives the generic as an argument just fine, wants an explicit type: `Mapper<type>().map(item)` does not work.

Answer (score 1):

From [Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/typealias-declaration):

> A type alias declaration introduces a named alias of an existing type
>   into your program. Type alias declarations are declared using the
>   keyword typealias and have the following form:

```
typealias name = existing type
```

> After a type alias is declared, the aliased name can be used instead
>   of the existing type everywhere in your program. The existing type can
>   be a named type or a compound type. Type aliases do not create new
>   types; they simply allow a name to refer to an existing type.

So you can use it like this:

```
typealias yourType = String

func doSomethingWithType(type: yourType) {

}
```